# SignalR ARGB from server to client

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, signalr

Can someone advise on how I can pass a set of ARGB values from a C# signalR server to the JS SIgnalR Client?

In other words, How can I pass a bunch of ARGB values from C# to Javascript in the most efficient way possible avoiding multiple loops?

Thanks.

Edit: This is for a remote PC viewing application. I want to send just the difference in pixels. What would be the best form for me to send it? Please feel free to let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Pass the values for what purpose? To display as an image?

Comment: yes I would like to pass it to display it as an image. yes

Comment: I have provided additional details now.

Answer (score 2):

You're not very specific in your question, but you could obviously send them in string in hex AARRGGBB format. You would literally just send a string message to the client, so to send three values of Red, Green and Blue you would do:

```
Clients.SendColors("FFFF0000FF00FF00FF0000FF");
```

Of course if you're asking for purposes of sending an actual bitmap image across the wire this is going to be highly inefficient. If you can add more detail to your question we might be able to offer more ideas.

Comment: I'm sorry for not making it more specific. This is for a team viewer like app. I need to send just the difference in pixels through the wire. If this is a very inefficient way, what do you suggest?

Comment: Well what your proposing is efficient in terms of design, but you're just limited in terms of format over the wire today. Knowing this now I would suggest you use base64 to encode the chunks of data. At least then you're only looking at a 1.37'ish size increase over actual data and you can decode this on the client. The trick will be decoding it efficiently, especially if you're pushing a huge amount of data through the wire. Some browsers (WebKit/Mozilla) have built in functions now, others have data URI hacks, etc. I leave that as an exercise for the reader to figure out. :)

Comment: Thank you Drew. It would've been great if there was lesser to figure out. anyways, I'll see what I can find with the clues you've provided.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not having used SignalR, it looks like you should be able to replace the default JSON serializer on the server side to add support for the object you are trying to serialize.  That being said, it just moves the loops elsewhere, and I am not sure what you would need to do on the client side to support the additional serialized format.

See https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Extensibility for an example.

Comment: Basically, I need to know the best way to transfer pixels through the wire.